# Highest quality website screenshot?

Tags: website-design, screenshot

I have created a [website](http://carselect.dk) that i would like to add to my portfolio, but i'm having a hard time getting high quality screenshots of the full site.
I tried to save the website as PDF, but that was full of errors, other online services cant recreate the images and so on.
I've also just tried to take regular screenshots on the mac at put it all together, but it really lost a lot of quality when i scaled it down.

Any good ideas? :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is happening, and perhaps a demo of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: When you say "portfolio", do you mean a _physical_ one (printed on paper), or a collection of pictures (JPG, PNG) that you can distribute on _digital media_ or online?

Comment: I am very interested why the mac screenshots the OP has tried are not any better than the solutions below.  I am not aware of any Hi Def screenshots, so if someone could please explain that one to me.  Further, I am also interested in the scaling problem.  Usually it is the other way around.  Of course, when you scale something down - there is less space for pixels to represent the image, but a loss of "quality"?  Maybe your zoom percent makes it appear this way? Try 100%

Comment: 1920x1080 screen resolution (1080p) gives an image *for printing* that is suitable for 6.4 x 3.6 inches

Answer (score 15):

In Firefox, you can open the console with `Shift+F2` and use `screenshot --fullpage`.

To scale it to different dimensions and sizes while preserving text quality, use `Ctrl+Shift+M` (or `Cmd+Opt+M` on OS X) to enter the responsive design viewer and resize as needed (you can also use this to get screenshots at higher resolution than your monitor supports, or get pictures of tablet/mobile views). No plug-ins necessary.

[Large example](http://s27.postimg.org/y6okxn1ox/Screen_Shot_2014_04_24_at_15_23_43.png)

[Small example](http://s27.postimg.org/u6hfleb81/Screen_Shot_2014_04_24_at_15_25_08.png)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to take a full page screenshot on a website you can use this [Google Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-screen/nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

This will makes several screenshots (while scrolling) and combine them into one .png image.

You just have to click on the plugin and choose "Capture entire page".

[image]

Comment: I personally use [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki?hl=en), it makes it quite easy to save the files.

Comment: The screenshots should be used in the portfolio on my own website. I've tried both Awesome Screenshot and Webpage Screenshot, but they are not working on the page I'm trying to capture.
The parallax effect ruins the screenshot and the elements that first appears when the user scrolls down to it, doesn't appear on the screenshot. I've looked at a few solutions that could convert the css to vector, which would be perfect, but they seems to ruin the structure of the page and can't handle the images.

Comment: parralax is an animation which cannot be captured in a still image. Try disabling the background images and then make a composite image using screencaps and the source files.

Comment: I use this too. It is awesome. It doesn't work on local files though. You need to host the html page first. There is also goog ol' print screen too. If you want a quick screen capture tool to capture the motion/parallax try [Screencast-o-matic](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/screen_recorder). It is web based and the video output is pretty good quality.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Faststone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), which you can also use outside the browser for anything else. Unfortunately, as mentioned by @McKeene, it has problems sticking the single images together to a big one because of the scrolling effect.

[Version 5.3 is free](http://www.chip.de/downloads/FastStone-Capture-Letzte-Freeware-Version_20749866.html) (German download) for home users. Otherwise latest version is around $20.

[image: FastStone Capture Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**Firefox users** just add a plugin called "Awesome Screenshot". 
To download this addon visit following link 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/

**Chrome Users can go to** 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en

this addon allows users to take screenshot of VISIBLE part as well as FULL PAGE, you can crop, insert shapes etc without switching to another program.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using [Pagelayers](http://www.pagelayers.com/) for mac and I'm pretty happy with it.

Some things that I love:

- Psd's can be generated at custom width & infinite height.
- The generated psd's are broken down into groups and layers.
- Can save to PNG directly

Some things that bother me:

- Requires the page to be loaded on the app.  No chrome extension. This
  can be quite tedious, especially when you just want a simple
  screenshot. (My biggest gripe with it)
- The generated psd file can be quite large.

Things you might not like:

Price: £20

I have a different use case for it therefore I can justify the price, however you might not if you just need simple screenshots.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone cares to read all the answers and wasn't satisfied with the above ones, which are also excellent, there is another screenshot [plugin for Firefox: "Screengrab!"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/). I don't know what resolution you can get, but the whole current page will be on the screenshot, not just the visible part. Aditionally, you can go and grab a specified selection or only the currently visible part of your screen, it saves to png format.

Comment: The resolution you get depends on the display configuration of the monitor you are using.