# What can I use to capture a screenshot of an entire web page?

Tags: software-recommendation, css, html, screenshot

I tried to capture the whole webpage using [this](http://web-capture.net/convert.php) screenshot tool but I am unable to capture the images. This is the url of the webpage: http://dabblet.com/gist/f1450f041e18287ce211

Comment: Snagit from tech smith makes this easy

Comment: We already have a similar question to this titled "[Highest quality website screenshot?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30081/highest-quality-website-screenshot)" so I marked this as a duplicate.  If any of those dont work please edit your question to reflect that and we can reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the screenshot service that you linked to works, but it probably uses a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to render the page and then to capture a screen shot. PhantomJS uses WebKit, the rendering engine that is used by Safari and the basis of the Chrome rendering engine.

Your site uses [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) which might make this task difficult.

Regardless, to capture a screenshot of an entire webpage, a good solution is to use an extension or add-on to your browser. Here are links for screenshot extensions for several good browsers:

Chrome: [Search Chrome Webstore for "screenshot"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/screenshot?hl=en)

Firefox: [Search Firefox addons for "screenshot"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=screenshot)

Safari: [Search Apple extensions for "screenshot"](https://extensions.apple.com/?q=screenshot)

Comment: I will check those.